# mysql ORDER BY isn't using the index when multiple fields are present in SELECT

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, optimization

I'm trying to simplify a query to figure out why it's so slow on the production server.  The idea is to grab the X most recent entries for pagination.  The problem is, MySQL's optimizer seems to want to use filesort instead of the Primary Key (`ID`).  Stripping away all the extraneous stuff, the following works as desired, using the index (primary):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ID FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC
```

However, these variations resort to filesort:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ID, field2 FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC
```

I need to return several fields, so that doesn't work...  I can get around the problem in the simplified query with:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table FORCE INDEX (Primary) ORDER BY ID DESC
```

but I haven't figured out how to work that into the larger query with table joins.  Am I missing something really simple?

Comment: Does forcing to use the index speed up the query? If you need to read all records of the table (as it looks like you do), maybe it does not make sense to use the index. "The idea is to grab the X most recent entries for pagination". Then there should be LIMIT clause somewhere. Otherwise the DB thinks you want them all.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention LIMIT clauses because that's part of what I stripped away for the above examples.  Having the LIMIT in place does not seem to have any effect -- it still uses filesort every time.  I didn't let it run for speed tests with the FORCE INDEX on the production server; that was only tested via EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from table order by id desc limit (pageNO-1) * noEntries , noEntries
```

eg for page 1 and 10 entries per page

```
 select * from table order by id desc limit 0, 10
```

eg for page 2 and 10 entries per page

```
select * from table order by id desc limit 10, 10
```

Comment: See my response to Thilo above.  Adding in the LIMIT clause still uses filesort.  That's the part that had me perplexed in the first place, leading me to strip away all the pieces until I could get a better idea of what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!  I went through numerous revisions and can't swear to which one was the key, but I think the main thing was running OPTIMIZE TABLE, which had the following cleanup effect:

```
Type        Usage
Data        241.2 KiB -> 239.4
Index       31,744 B  -> 26,624
Overhead    136 B     -> 0
Effective   272.0 KiB
Total       272.2 KiB -> 265.4
```

With that, I was able to run "EXPLAIN SELECT ID, field2 FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0,10" without it resorting to filesort, so that was a good start.  From there, I began building up the main query again and was running into problems with DISTINCT(ID) keeping it from using the Primary Key as an index.  It needed to be there, though, because one of the tables that the ID field joins has multiple entries for each ID.  However, replacing DISTINCT(ID) with GROUP BY ID did the trick.  That didn't work previously, so I'm wondering if it had something to do with the OPTIMIZE TABLE?  Anyway, thanks for the attempted help while I plugged away at it!

Comment: It's sort of implied, but I should mention that getting the query to use the index instead of filesort had a huge impact on performance.  Before, it would hang seemingly indefinitely, and now it is nearly instantaneous.